# Spring Boot:How to display image from system directory in spring boot application?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working with spring boot I want to display image from my system directory in html page but i cannot do that.
Any can help me please.

> > This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<img alt="no image" src="D:\images\fav-icon">
</body>
```

> > I tried the following code also but it is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<img alt="no data" th:src="@{D:\images\1r-product-6.jpg}">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry
        .addResourceHandler("/images/**")
        .addResourceLocations("file:resources/","file:uploads/","file:/your-image-path")
        .setCachePeriod(0);
}
}
```

add your image path in `addResourceLocations`.

**If you are Windows user then add path like this:  `"file:D:\\imagepath\")`

Comment: thanks from your answer .But what should i give as value in src property of image tag in html page.

Comment: you give path /images:   @{/images/thymeleaf.png}

Comment: thymeleaf.png is the nome of image with its extension?

Comment: i just give example

Comment: you use your image-name

Comment: Sajib iam giving this path but it is trowing exception:<img alt="no data" th:src="images:@{D:\BurkaFarkharImages\1r-product-6.jpg}">

Comment: D:\BurkaFarkharImages this path add resourceLocation

Comment: sajib iam give this path but still giving exception:<img alt="no data" th:src="@{images\1r-product-6.jpg"> and configuration class: .addResourceLocations("file:resources/","file:uploads/","file:/D:\\BurkaFarkharImages")

Comment: thanks sajib I resolved the issue:configuration:.addResourceLocations("file:D:\\BurkaFarkharImages/") and in html: <img alt="no image" th:src="@{/images/1r-product-6.jpg}">

Comment: glad. i gave solution for ubuntu user